# Multithreaded application in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I haven't worked with Java threads in several years so I have a very basic question about multithreading.  I'm writing a java package that will be called by another language (matlab).  Matlab is able to instantiate a Java class and run java code.

I want to be able to:

1. Start multiple threads
2. Get a list of all running threads
3. Stop a given thread by name
4. Stop all threads

I used the `Thread` class in the past, but are there any easier/more complete packages available now?  Can anyone provide a simple demo or point me to a tutorial on the subject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe have a look at the examples in the [online supplement](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/) of *Concurrent Programming in Java: Design Principles and Patterns* by Doug Lea which is **the** book on Threads and concurrent programming (but it doesn't cover the new `java.util.concurrent` package).

Or check the more recent *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz, Tim Peierls, Joshua Bloch, Joseph Bowbeer, David Holmes, Doug Lea (a dream team for such a book) and its [companion website](http://jcip.net/).

Answer (score 3):

How about [Sun's own tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) on the subject?

Answer (score 3):

The [Executor](http://www.uni-muenster.de/ZIV.BennoSueselbeck/java/jdk1.5.0_01/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface provides a lot of useful methods for managing and executing threads, I would suggest taking a look at that.  There's also an [Executors](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class which provides different thread pooling options, and there's some good information [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Comment: Afaik, the Executors have no way to control threads by name. Once a Task or Runnable is submitted, there is no control any more.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: if you need to be able to stop threads (safely), you need to code them so that they respond correctly to `Thread.interrupt()`.  For example, a compute intensive thread needs to check the `interrupted` flag occasionally, and IO requests need to be done using APIs that allow a blocking call to be interrupted.  This is not simple ...